# Angular chart js bar chart width not working

Tags: angular, typescript, charts

I'm using angular 12 and chart js latest version for the my project I'm try to do bar chart width small but  `barPercentage: 0.4` cant added to my code any solution?

**here the code**

```
var myChart = new Chart('myChart', {
      type: 'bar',
      data: {
        labels: this.labels,
        datasets: [
          {
            data: this.data,
            backgroundColor: [' rgba(148, 180, 214,0.4)', 'rgba(239, 83, 80,0.4)', 'rgba(102, 187, 106,0.4)'],
            borderColor: [' #93b3d6', '#ef5350', '#66bb6a'],borderWidth: 1
          },
        ],
      },
      options: {
        plugins: {
          legend: {
            display: false,
          },
        },
        responsive: true,
        maintainAspectRatio: true,
        datasets: {
          bar: {
            categoryPercentage: 0.95
          }
        },
        scales: {
          y: {
            title: {
              display: true,
              text: 'Count',
            },
          },
          x: {
            title: {
              display: false,
              text: 'Total Count',
            },
          },
        },
      },
    });
```

Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should add `barPercentage` in each of your `dataset`.

````
 datasets: [
          {
            data: this.data,
            backgroundColor: [' rgba(148, 180, 214,0.4)', 'rgba(239, 83, 80,0.4)', 'rgba(102, 187, 106,0.4)'],
            borderColor: [' #93b3d6', '#ef5350', '#66bb6a'],
            borderWidth: 1,
            barPercentage: 0.4
          },
        ],
    ```
````

Answer (score 0):

Finally I found the solution I added  in  to the datasets

```
   datasets: {
                  bar: {
                    barThickness: 50,
                    barPercentage: 0.5,
                  }
                },
```